# face_recognition.face_encodings causes crash program python

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I am trying to do live/ real-time face_recognition using webcam. I am using :
face_recognition version 1.2.8
python version 3.10.6
opencv version 4.5.5

I try to execute this program : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam.py

by running : python3 facerec_from_webcam.py

the webcam starts, then it stopped immediately, the program crashes

I have this error :

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/stacy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/stacy/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py", line 55, in <module>
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

  File "/home/stacy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in face_encodings

    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]

  File "/home/stacy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>

    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]

TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:

    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector

    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector

    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss

    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors



Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x7fd0a822a430>, array([[[163, 141, 133],

        [164, 138, 133],

        [167, 139, 131],

        ...,

        [172, 152, 148],

        [174, 147, 152],

        [174, 148, 148]],



       [[166, 140, 135],

        [166, 141, 135],

        [165, 141, 130],

        ...,

        [172, 152, 152],

        [172, 151, 149],

        [171, 153, 146]],



       [[166, 143, 136],

        [163, 143, 131],

        [161, 144, 131],

        ...,

        [175, 155, 156],

        [171, 152, 151],

        [169, 153, 150]],



       ...,



       [[168, 167, 166],

        [  5,  12,  21],

        [ 11,  19,  24],

        ...,

        [176, 125,  90],

        [168, 132, 114],

        [166, 163, 165]],



       [[132, 146, 152],

        [ 14,  21,  34],

        [ 15,  20,  23],

        ...,

        [176, 126, 107],

        [176, 157, 155],

        [162, 162, 165]],



       [[ 22,  37,  64],

        [ 19,  23,  37],

        [ 18,  20,  27],

        ...,

        [ 65,  54,  84],

        [169, 180, 202],

        [145, 156, 166]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x7fd0a8231af0>, 1
```

I tried to remove this line : face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations).

The program doesn't crash, but it doesn't recognize faces in the webcam.

Dooes someone know what is the problem and how I could fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [face\_recognition problem with face\_encodings function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926662/face-recognition-problem-with-face-encodings-function)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and figured out this to resolve my problem.
Replace the code line,

```
rgb_small_frame = frame_process[:, :, ::-1]
```

with this code line,

```
rgb_small_frame = numpy.ascontiguousarray(frame_process[:, :, ::-1])
```

You have to install numpy package for this solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).