# face_recognition problem with face_encodings function

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, dlib

I am a newbie and having difficulty on resolving this issue.

What I am trying to do is run the sample code from [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) using a webcam. Both of the two example doesn't work on me and keeps on throwing this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\face_recognition\demo_webcam.py", line 55, in <module>
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>  
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x000001DAB486B7B0>, array([[[208, 223, 240],
        [204, 213, 234],
        [191, 208, 229],
        ...,
        [ 87,  76,  74],
        [ 94,  78,  77],
        [ 82,  72,  70]],

       [[214, 223, 245],
        [208, 221, 240],
        [197, 217, 235],
        ...,
        [100,  63,  68],
        [104,  74,  71],
        [ 87,  78,  75]],

       [[220, 231, 249],
        [218, 228, 245],
        [208, 224, 239],
        ...,
        [ 96,  86,  84],
        [102,  83,  82],
        [ 86,  83,  80]],

       ...,

       [[ 36,  36,  35],
        [ 41,  37,  36],
        [ 40,  35,  33],
        ...,
        [107,  65,  41],
        [109,  67,  44],
        [109,  68,  50]],

       [[ 41,  39,  38],
        [ 42,  36,  35],
        [ 44,  39,  38],
        ...,
        [107,  64,  45],
        [106,  62,  42],
        [108,  64,  42]],

       [[ 46,  42,  41],
        [ 45,  39,  38],
        [ 43,  38,  36],
        ...,
        [104,  67,  51],
        [100,  64,  46],
        [108,  64,  40]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x000001DAB4EF0370>, 1
```

I am using Python 3.11.2 running on Windows 11. I have face_recognition v1.3.0 and dlib v19.24.1.

I already tried reinstalling everything based on the installation guide from face_recognition.

Comment: you may consider to adopt deepface. It has a stream function running facial recognition on webcam directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please replace the code line,

```
rgb_small_frame = frame_process[:, :, ::-1]
```

with below code line,

```
rgb_small_frame = numpy.ascontiguousarray(frame_process[:, :, ::-1])
```

Comment: alternatively: `rgb_small_frame = cv2.cvtColor(small_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Answer (score 2):

Load the reference face image:

```
reference_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/home/computer/Imagens/profile.jpeg")
reference_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(reference_image)[0]
```

Open a connection to the webcam (you may need to adjust the index based on your system):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Video capture read loop:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Convert the frame to RGB for face recognition:

```
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Perform face detection:

```
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)
```

Compare the current face with the reference face:

```
    for face_encoding in face_encodings:
        results = face_recognition.compare_faces([reference_encoding], face_encoding)
        name = "Match" if True in results else "No Match"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

rgb_small_frame = cv2.cvtColor(small_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

your code worked bex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).